# VBA: sum row values separately based on repeating criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a VBA code to sum the values of rows as long as the value is "1", then sum the values of rows as long as the value is "-1", then loop it until the row is empty.

See attached screen-shot

[image]

Please note that the criteria does not repeat 5x, instead it changes frequently.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Shai, I really haven't tried to come up with the code yet. I was browsing thru to see if there were relevant posts in the past which I can adapt to what I actually wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If your data starts at `A2`, use this formula at `C2` then copy/paste in column `C`:

```
=IF(B2=B1,"",SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(A2,,,MATCH(TRUE,B3:B$1000<>B2,0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code, which seems to work. It expects you to select the column with the values to be summed (not any blanks at the end), and based on the column to the right, adds the relevant totals to the third column.

```
Sub MyProc()

Dim inputRange As Range
Set inputRange = Selection

Dim Cell As Range
Dim RunningTotal As Integer
Dim VerticalOffset As Integer

Dim PreviousCellFlag As Integer
PreviousCellFlag = 0

For Each Cell In inputRange

    If Cell.Offset(0, 1) <> PreviousCellFlag Then

        PreviousCellFlag = Cell.Offset(0, 1)
        RunningTotal = 0
        VerticalOffset = 0

        While Cell.Offset(0, 1) = Cell.Offset(VerticalOffset, 1)
            RunningTotal = RunningTotal + Cell.Offset(VerticalOffset, 0).Value
            VerticalOffset = VerticalOffset + 1
        Wend

        Cell.Offset(0, 2) = RunningTotal
    Else
        Cell.Offset(0, 2) = ""
    End If

Next Cell

End Sub
```